# JLong to Double type casting with Delphi

Tags: java, android, c++, delphi, c++builder

I searched online how to cast a JLong (JavaType) to a Double to use it in C++ code but didn't find examples.
I tried various ways to cast this JLong but none work.

```
function TimeSinceBoot(const aContext: JContext): Double;
  begin
    result := (((TJSystemClock.JavaClass.ELAPSED_REALTIME div 1000(JLong)) div 60(JLong))(JDouble))(Double);
  end;
```

It says still ***Operator or ; missing.***
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Typecasting in Delphi goes like `Type(Value)`, not `Value(Type)`.

Comment: Typecasting in Delphi is documented. It's always depressing when people who don't know stuff ask before reading the documentation.

Comment: `var
        val: JLong;

      begin
        val:= JLong(60000);`
**"Incorrect transtyping"**, I'm not talking about JavaTypes for nothing...

Comment: @IDS: Java's [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) (uppercase) is a class type wrapper for a primitive `long` (lowercase)  value. Delphi's `JLong` is an interface wrapper for `Long`. You can't type-cast an integer to an interface and back. In your example, you have to use Delphi's `TJLong` wrapper class to perform the conversion, eg: `val := TJLong.JavaClass.init(60000);` To go the other way, simply call the `JLong.doubleValue()` (or similar) method, eg: `var val: JLong; dbl: Double; begin val := TJLong.JavaClass.init(60000); dbl := val.doubleValue;`

Comment: Thanks Remy it works :) I understand JClass -> Interface, TJClass -> Wrappers now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you *use the wrong syntax to cast* (and the cast syntax is [well documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Typecasts)), in Delphi, [*you can't cast an integral type to a floating point type*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/E2089_Invalid_typecast_(Delphi)) anyway. And you certainly can't cast a JLong to a double.

But apparently, in the Delphi translation, `JLong` is an interface with a method called `doubleValue`. Use that:

```
Result := TJSystemClock.JavaClass.ELAPSED_REALTIME.doubleValue / 60000.0;
```

Comment: Operator do not work for this type of operand...
ELAPSED_REALTIME is a JLong.

Comment: Ah, I see that in the translation, a JLong is an interface. And that has a method called `doubleValue`.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, wasn't obvious in the compiling error. It compiles right now ! The Androidapi.JNIMarshal.pas is apparently not found by RAD Studio when executing the app tho. I didn't call it myself and app wasn't missing any Androidapi before x)